# Need to combine a string and a object into like query params string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, query-string

As the titles says, I have a string and I have a object.

I have to following data

```
id: 2319213213
```

Object

```
{ personName: 'John', personId: 123213213, personGender: 'Male' }
```

**Note: This object I will getting have many properties and all of them can be optional.**

Need to combine these and make a string like top in JavaScript/TypeScript

Expected Result

```
2319213213?personId=123213213&personName=John&personGender=Male
```

Comment: lookup `URLSearchParams` documentation

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @User863 please check the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `URLSearchParams`:

```js
const id = 2319213213
    
const person = {
    personName: 'John',
    personId: 123213213,
    personGender: 'Male'
  }

const result = id + '?' +  new URLSearchParams(person)
console.log(result)
```